# Why would my Input Property Binding not work? - Angular

Tags: angular, property-binding

I am getting the property as undefined when attempting input property binding.
Component with inputs:
like.component.ts
`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'like',
  templateUrl: './like.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./like.component.css']
})
export class LikeComponent{
  @Input('is-liked') isLiked: boolean;
  @Input('likes-count') likesCount: number;


  onClick(){
    console.log("clicked");
    console.log(this.likesCount);
    console.log(this.isLiked);
    this.likesCount += (this.isLiked) ? -1 : 1;
    this.isLiked = !this.isLiked;

  }

}
```

`
like.component.html

```
<p>
  likes work
</p>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"
      [class.highlighted]="isLiked"
      (click)=onClick()></span>
<span>{{ likesCount }}</span>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LikeComponent } from './like/like.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    isSelected = true;
    likesCount = 5;


}
```

app.component.html

```
<like 
[likes-count]="likesCount"
[is-liked]="isSelected"
></like>
```

I declare the input properties in the Like Component and then bind them in the app component - but it seems the values are not being passed:
[Developer Tools Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD0be.png)

Answer (score 1):

In app.module.ts I had

```
 bootstrap: [AppComponent, LikeComponent]
```

and changed it to:

```
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

now the properties bind as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should just have

```
<like 
[likescount]="likesCount"
[isliked]="isSelected"
></like>
```

and

```
 @Input() isLiked: boolean;
 @Input() likesCount: number;
```

**[`DEMO STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction-qpexck?file=app%2Flike.component.ts)**

Comment: That is not working for me either. I saw some posts that you should avoid camel casing in HTML but that is what I started with.

Comment: I attached a screenshot of the console output from developer tools to the end. I have not used stackblitz but will work on that later.

Comment: CHECK THE DEMO https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction-qpexck?file=app%2Flike.component.ts

Comment: @Vikas i have just added the component interaction part, logic OP has to deat with

Comment: It was because I had 'LikeComponent' listed in the bootstrap piece with 'AppComponent'. Thanks for the demo! I will use stackblitz in the future. So changing  bootstrap: [AppComponent, LikeComponent] ->  bootstrap: [AppComponent] fixed the issue.

Comment: It won't let me mark it yet. I do not have enough points as I just created an account. Once I get more I will mark. I posted the fix but will upvote this thread.